# SQL Joined Table Lookup With Conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

I'm looking to join two tables, the criteria is that if the users table has anything in the branch code field then the SQL query will only return their branch code.

If however the users table has a NULL in the branch code box it will return all of the branch codes in the branches table.

Below is what I was trying and I know doesn't work but should give some inclination of the tables and fields I'm using.

```
SELECT IF(u.BranchCode IS NOT NULL THEN b.BranchCode ELSE u.BranchCode END ) AS BranchCode, b.BranchName, b.BranchAddress1, b.BranchAddress2
FROM users AS u
LEFT JOIN branches AS b ON u.BranchCode = b.BranchCode
WHERE u.Username = '$_SESSION[USERNAME]'
```

Some table examples:

Users

```
UserName |  BranchCode
---------|------------------
bob      | NULL
sam      | AW3456
dave     | NULL
alison   | NULL
fred     | NULL
```

Branches

```
BranchCode| BranchName  |BranchAddress1 |BranchAddress2
----------|-------------|---------------|-------------------
AQ3459    | Northmore   |1 Northmore Rd |Northmore Village
AW3456    | Middleton   |28 Main Rd     |Middleton Stoney
DE5689    | Western     |451 Station Rd |Western
FR3278    | Easterly    |12 Acacia Dr   |Easterly Estate
```

So for example if bob is the user logging in it will return ALL of the BranchCode info:

```
BranchCode| BranchName  |BranchAddress1 |BranchAddress2
----------|-------------|---------------|-------------------
AQ3459    | Northmore   |1 Northmore Rd |Northmore Village
AW3456    | Middleton   |28 Main Rd     |Middleton Stoney
DE5689    | Western     |451 Station Rd |Western
FR3278    | Easterly    |12 Acacia Dr   |Easterly Estate
```

if sam is the user logging in it will return ONLY the lookup of his BranchCode info as it's specified in the users table:

```
BranchCode| BranchName  |BranchAddress1 |BranchAddress2
----------|-------------|---------------|-------------------
AW3456    | Middleton   |28 Main Rd     |Middleton Stoney
```

Comment: You mean to say, you want all that data From branch table which are not linked with user table?

Comment: I'd be lying if I said I wasn't a touch confused by your SQL. Is there any way you could give us a quick column explanation for both tables and some dummy data?

Comment: @Jhecht - I deleted my comment after re-reading that this is `LEFT JOIN` /slaps_forehead

Comment: @Palendrone, thanks for the edit. I don't generally use IF statements with SQL, so give me a second to setup a SQLFiddle to work this out, unless someone posts an answer.

Comment: Is there any reason that the `branchId` value isn't stored in the `$_SESSION` variable? I can only guess from your code that a query to the users table has already been done. If you would store the branch id in the session, this could effectively make a lot of things easier (read: I'm still working on it, but not getting far)

Comment: The system I use is the the user logs in, the next page has drop down with all the BranchCodes Listed out, from here you choose your branch code then it's stored as a $_SESSION variable, my thought train was that if the user had a specific branch code assigned to the user account he/she could only select their branch and no one else's. Thanks for the effort though :0)

Comment: Tried in sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a8344/21 but don't have an answer for you. The first query would work in SQL Server (tested), second one was a trial and last one would work other than the apparent constraint on returning more than one result in subquery. Unfortunately, SQL Server is my area and I'm unfamiliar with the nuances/differences with mySQL. Hopefully one of them may put you on the right track

Comment: ok didn't know how to comment queries in fiddle (and can't edit comments after 5 minutes on here) so there's only one there, apologies. Can give you code to get this to work in SQL Server if it would help, sadly can't do the same in mySQL. Best of luck finding an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps someone who is better with SQL will come along and answer this question in a pure SQL fashion, but I tend to keep my queries fairly simple as I like to follow the KISS rule in my coding. And I hope they do, since this answer doesn't 100% answer your question in the manner you would like.

With the SQL you gave us, I can assume you are using PHP for this query. Also, from your query it seems apparent that you have previously made a call to the users table. In THAT call, store the `BranchId` column in the session, as you are with your username variable.

With the assumption that `$_SESSION['branchId']` is set (even though it may be NULL) and your `mysqli_connect()` call is stored in a variable named `$con`, you can then do something like this:

## To Answer The Question (but not really)

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM branches";

if($_SESSION['branchId']!==null){
   $sql.= " WHERE BranchCode='".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_SESSION['branchId'])."'";
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
//Fetch rows as usual.
```

## Notes About Table Structure

If you already have ID columns for your tables, then feel free to ignore the next portion.

Now, I am really not sure about why your table is structured the way that it is. I understand that each branch may have an alphanumeric call number when conversing (e.g. if you called another branch, you would say something like "I am Jack from branch AW2011, ...") but [SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) is real, and one of the best and simplest ways to counter it is to typecast references variables so that any extra input is removed. However, that's only useful for reference columns that are integer typed, as string columns still need escaped. With that in mind, you will notice that I used `mysqli_real_escape_string()` around the branchId, because I knew it was going to be a string value.

A lot of people are going to recommend things like [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and while I may have provided you the link for it, it can sometimes be very confusing, and I'm not entirely a huge fan of PHP's PDO connection. The MySQLi extension also provides its own version of statement preparation, neither of which strike me immediately as amazing. They both seem complicated, and I feel needlessly so. But they are definitely the best way to avoid SQL Injection should you need to use string data.

Without any more reference on your tables, I can't be certain as what your data actually looks like, but my logic here is that if you had a user_id column, you wouldn't be passing in the username column. As such, I recommend that every record on ANY table you make to have an ID column. This simplifies guarding against SQL Injection, because instead of the length `mysql_real_escape_string()` call, I can shorten the text in the `if()` statement to

```
$sql .= 'WHERE branch_id='.(int)$_SESSION['branchId'];
```

And in most cases, that should be nearly all you would need to guard against a SQL Injection. IF someone were to alter your session data (which I'm sure is possible, though never decided to try) any extra text they attempted to input would either be deleted or cause the SQL to run improperly. (Don't quote me on this, however. what I read about PHP typecasting variables I read a long time ago, so I could be entirely wrong).

If you are unclear about what an ID column is or how to use it, please feel free to ask another question and hopefully someone much more precise than I could explain it to you.

Comment: Huge thank you for your thoughts and a potential work around, I will have a look at implementing this method via the PHP, a very good solution.

Answer (score 1):

Just to show a way to do this in pure SQL.

You may do an UNION, one part using an INNER JOIN, the other using a CROSS JOIN (as there's no relation between the two tables in this case)

```
select b.BranchCode, b.BranchName, b.BranchAddress1, b.BranchAddress2
from users u
inner join branches b on u.BranchCode = b.BranchCode
where u.UserName = '$_SESSION'
and u.BranchCode is not null -- just for clarity, it's not neeeded
union
select b.BranchCode, b.BranchName, b.BranchAddress1, b.BranchAddress2
from branches b
CROSS JOIN users u
where u.UserName = '$_SESSION[USERNAME]'
and u.BranchCode is null
```

see [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a8344/28) (I added the UserName to understand better what's happening with two users, one with NULL BranchCode, one with valid BranchCode)